# Somar o valor total de determinada coluna para cada tabela - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(valor,2,'de_DE') AS valor,
       DATE_FORMAT(data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       realizado,
       DATE_FORMAT(data_realizado, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_realizado,
       parcelas,
       numero_parcela,
       observacoes,
       lancamento,
       tipo_movimento,
       tipo,
       id_usuario
FROM
  (SELECT r.valor_receita AS valor,
          r.data_vencimento AS data_vencimento,
          r.recebido AS realizado,
          r.data_recebimento AS data_realizado,
          r.parcelas AS parcelas,
          r.numero_parcela AS numero_parcela,
          r.observacoes AS observacoes,
          'Receita' AS lancamento,
          re.tipo_recebimento AS tipo_movimento,
          tr.tipo_receita AS tipo,
          r.id_usuario AS id_usuario
   FROM receitas AS r
   INNER JOIN tipo_receita AS tr ON (r.id_tipo_receita = tr.id_tipo_receita)
   INNER JOIN tipo_recebimento AS re ON (r.id_tipo_recebimento = re.id_tipo_recebimento)
   UNION SELECT d.valor_despesa AS valor,
                d.data_vencimento AS data_vencimento,
                d.pago AS realizado,
                d.data_pagamento AS data_realizado,
                d.parcelas AS parcelas,
                d.numero_parcela AS numero_parcela,
                d.observacoes AS observacoes,
                c.nome_categoria AS lancamento,
                tp.tipo_pagamento AS tipo_movimento,
                td.tipo_despesa AS tipo,
                d.id_usuario AS id_usuario
   FROM despesas AS d
   INNER JOIN tipo_despesa AS td ON (d.id_tipo_despesa = td.id_tipo_despesa)
   INNER JOIN tipo_pagamento AS tp ON (d.id_tipo_pagamento = tp.id_tipo_pagamento)
   INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON (td.id_categoria = c.id_categoria)) AS origem
WHERE id_usuario = 1
```

Quero saber como fazer para adicionar duas colunas, uma que some o `valor_receita` (total) da tabela receitas, e a outra que some o `valor_despesa` (total) da tabela despesas.

Tabelas: https://pastebin.com/rexcXTKw

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim, coloca antes do FROM.

`(SELECT SUM(valor_receita) FROM tabela_receitas) AS total_receita,
(SELECT SUM(valor_despesa) FROM tabela_despesas) AS total_despesa`

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso, porém, estou passando alguns filtros no código PHP pra incrementar a query. Aí tem que ser o valor total baseado nesse filtro tbm.

Comment: SUM(r.valor_receita) AS total_receita, ai vai somar só os valores dos registros encontrados

Comment: Dessa forma só retorna um registro.. e não todos

Comment: Dá um GROUP BY id_receita, id_despesas, você pode simplificar e fazer duas consultas, uma para saber o valor de receitas e outra de despesas.

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim, [talvez tenha de fazer outro group by/sum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/466202/join-avan%C3%A7ado-em-firebird-n%C3%A3o-consigo-juntar-as-tabelas-que-preciso-e-ordenar/466240#466240)

```
SELECT FORMAT(valor_receita,2,'de_DE') AS valor_receita,
       FORMAT(valor_despesa,2,'de_DE') AS valor_despesa,
       DATE_FORMAT(data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       realizado,
       DATE_FORMAT(data_realizado, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_realizado,
       parcelas,
       numero_parcela,
       observacoes,
       lancamento,
       tipo_movimento,
       tipo,
       id_usuario
FROM
  (SELECT r.valor_receita AS valor_receita,
          0 as valor_despesa,
          r.data_vencimento AS data_vencimento,
          r.recebido AS realizado,
          r.data_recebimento AS data_realizado,
          r.parcelas AS parcelas,
          r.numero_parcela AS numero_parcela,
          r.observacoes AS observacoes,
          'Receita' AS lancamento,
          re.tipo_recebimento AS tipo_movimento,
          tr.tipo_receita AS tipo,
          r.id_usuario AS id_usuario
   FROM receitas AS r
   INNER JOIN tipo_receita AS tr ON (r.id_tipo_receita = tr.id_tipo_receita)
   INNER JOIN tipo_recebimento AS re ON (r.id_tipo_recebimento = re.id_tipo_recebimento)
   UNION 
   SELECT   0 AS valor_receita,
            d.valor_despesa AS valor_despesa,
            d.data_vencimento AS data_vencimento,
            d.pago AS realizado,
            d.data_pagamento AS data_realizado,
            d.parcelas AS parcelas,
            d.numero_parcela AS numero_parcela,
            d.observacoes AS observacoes,
            c.nome_categoria AS lancamento,
            tp.tipo_pagamento AS tipo_movimento,
            td.tipo_despesa AS tipo,
            d.id_usuario AS id_usuario
   FROM despesas AS d
   INNER JOIN tipo_despesa AS td ON (d.id_tipo_despesa = td.id_tipo_despesa)
   INNER JOIN tipo_pagamento AS tp ON (d.id_tipo_pagamento = tp.id_tipo_pagamento)
   INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON (td.id_categoria = c.id_categoria)) AS origem
WHERE id_usuario = 1
```