# Join avançado em Firebird - Não consigo juntar as tabelas que preciso e ordenar no resultado correto

Tags: sql, join, firebase-database

Boa noite pessoal. Estou com uma demanda que vem esgotando meus neuronios ha uma semana e ainda nao conseguí encontrar a solução.

Num ERP utilizado por um cliente, surgiu a demanda de visualizar valor de compra vs venda, agrupado por seção(classificação mercadologica. Ex.: Cereais, Laticinios, Matinais, Frios e etc).

Eu consigo realizar em consultas separadas. Uma para compra e outra para venda:

Query compra:

```
SELECT 
A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, SUM(C.ITEVLRTOT) AS COMPRA FROM ITEM_ENTRADA AS C

JOIN 
PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD 

JOIN 
SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD 

JOIN 
ENTRADA AS D ON C.ENTDOC = D.ENTDOC
 
WHERE D.ENTDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-07-30' GROUP BY A.SECCOD,B.SECDES
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado Query acima, exibindo valores de compra agrupados por secao]

Query Venda

```
    SELECT A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, SUM (C.ITVVLRTOT) AS VENDA FROM ITEVDA AS C
    
    JOIN 
    PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD 
    
    JOIN
    SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD
    
    
    JOIN TRANSACAO AS D ON (D.TRNSEQ = C.TRNSEQ AND D.CXANUM = C.CXANUM AND D.TRNDAT = C.TRNDAT) 
    AND (D.TRNDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
    AND (D.TRNTIP = '1') AND (C.ITVTIP <> '2') 
    WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY A.SECCOD, B.SECDES ORDER BY 
    A.SECCOD ASC
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado Query acima, exibindo valores de venda agrupados por secao]

O que preciso é SECCOD, SECDES, TOTAL_COMPRA, TOTAL_VENDA. Porém não consigo. O mais proximo que cheguei, o filtro de data so era aplicado ou na compra, ou na venda.

Existe alguma possibilidade de fazer esta consulta da forma como desejo?

Comment: Recomendo colocar a saída esperada e o SQL no site http://sqlfiddle.com/ para podermos te ajudar melhor

Comment: Tente union , veja se isto ajuda https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/586346-select-resumo-em-v%C3%A1rias-tabelas/?do=findComment&comment=2287737

Comment: @Motta, tentei com o 'UNION ALL', porém ele põe os resultados logo abaixo do primeiro select. Fica assim: (colunas exibidas) 'Select1: SECCOD, SECDES, COMPRA' Select2: 'SECCOD, SECDES, VENDA'. Eu queria o resultado assim: 'SECCOD, SECDES, COMPRA, VENDA'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma das formas de resolver o seu problema é utilizando subconsultas com alias e join ou left join, dependendo da situação, conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT COMP.*, VEND.VENDA FROM (
        SELECT A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, SUM(C.ITEVLRTOT) AS COMPRA FROM ITEM_ENTRADA AS C
    
        JOIN PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD 
    
        JOIN SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD 
    
        JOIN ENTRADA AS D ON C.ENTDOC = D.ENTDOC
     
        WHERE D.ENTDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-07-30' GROUP BY A.SECCOD,B.SECDES
) AS COMP
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, SUM (C.ITVVLRTOT) AS VENDA FROM ITEVDA AS C
        
        JOIN 
        PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD 
        
        JOIN
        SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD
        
        
        JOIN TRANSACAO AS D ON (D.TRNSEQ = C.TRNSEQ AND D.CXANUM = C.CXANUM AND D.TRNDAT = C.TRNDAT) 
        AND (D.TRNDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
        AND (D.TRNTIP = '1') AND (C.ITVTIP <> '2') 
        WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY A.SECCOD, B.SECDES ORDER BY 
        A.SECCOD ASC
) AS VEND
    ON COMP.SECCOD = VEND.SECCOD
    AND COMP.SECDES = VEND.SECDES
```

Comment: muito obrigado por ajudar. Assim que possível, realizarei os testes e comento o resultado aqui. E para ir adiantando, já vou estudar um pouco sobre subconsultas.

Comment: resolveu. É isto mesmo viu. Na segunda consulta, utilizei somente o **JOIN**. O desempenho foi mais rapido e nao houve alteração nos valores do resultado. Seguindo a mesma lógica, posso criar uma subquery para realizar uma operação? Ex.: (VENDA / COMPRA)

Comment: Se fala de operações matemáticas, sim, segue um exemplo: `SELECT COMP.*, VEND.VENDA, (VEND.VENDA / COMP.COMPRA) AS DIVISAO FROM (...`.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Vou já vou testar aqui. Vcs são feras hein. Vc tem alguma indicação de curso para aprender SQL avançado assim? lógico que tem a parte da experiencia também né. Mas queria algo para dar um norte.

Comment: A indicação de material de estudos é muito subjetiva, vai de cada um, melhor você pesquisar e achar por conta própria, existe bastante coisa. A maior parte do conhecimento em SQL serve para qualquer banco de dados. No tangente ao firebird, existe material no site oficial dele em https://firebirdsql.org/, infelizmente parece que não tem em português.

Comment: encontrei um detalhe: no periodo em que nao houve compra numa determinada seção, nao é exibido o valor da venda na mesma. Isto se dá por conta do final da subconsulta ne, que exige o SECCOD da compra ser igual ao SECCOD da venda.

Comment: Por isso que usei o left join, com left join lista as compras, sem left join, vai listar somente as compras que já tenham venda. De acordo com o que você precisa, deve usar ou não o left.

Comment: como faço entao para que mesmo nao havendo compras no período, seja mostrado o valor das vendas?

Comment: Inverte a ordem da consulta acima, coloca o left join na sub consulta das compras.

Answer (score -2):

Solução com join

```
SELECT SECCOD, SECDES, SUM(COMPRA) AS COMPRA , SUM(VENDA) AS VENDA
FROM
(SELECT 
A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, SUM(C.ITEVLRTOT) AS COMPRA , 0 VENDA
FROM ITEM_ENTRADA AS CJOIN 
PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD 
JOIN 
SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD 
JOIN 
ENTRADA AS D ON C.ENTDOC = D.ENTDOC 
WHERE D.ENTDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-07-30' GROUP BY A.SECCOD,B.SECDES
UNION ALL
SELECT A.SECCOD, B.SECDES, 0 COMPRA , SUM (C.ITVVLRTOT) AS VENDA 
FROM ITEVDA AS C   
JOIN 
PRODUTO AS A ON C.PROCOD = A.PROCOD     
JOIN
SECAO AS B ON A.SECCOD = B.SECCOD      
JOIN TRANSACAO AS D ON (D.TRNSEQ = C.TRNSEQ AND D.CXANUM = C.CXANUM AND D.TRNDAT = C.TRNDAT) 
AND (D.TRNDAT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
AND (D.TRNTIP = '1') AND (C.ITVTIP <> '2') 
WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY A.SECCOD, B.SECDES ORDER BY 
A.SECCOD ASC
) VIRTUAL
GROUP BY SECCOD, SECDES
```

Comment: obrigado. Gostei desta também. So precisei retirar o comando ORDER BY do segundo select. Nesta forma como vc sugeriu, acho que vai ser mais fácil obter mais uma coluna (VENDA / (DIVIDIDO POR) COMPRA). Creio que basta criar mais duas consultas COMPRA1 e VENDA1, repetindo os mesmos parametros. Esta foi a melhor maneira que encontrei. Rsrsrs Mas creio que existe uma forma melhor para economizar código. Enfim, obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: aí teria de conhecer bem regras de negócio e as tabelas , em geral o union é bom pois permite juntar o caso zerado fazendo mais um union para produtos