# Como efetuar a soma das colunas sem multiplicar as somas?

Tags: sql, query, group-by

Quando executo esta query ele soma as colunas várias vezes no mesmo número de saídas na tabela itemsaida.

```
select p.idproduto codigo,
p.descricaoproduto nome,
sum(e.qtde) entrada,
sum(s.qtde) saida,
(sum(e.qtde) - sum(s.qtde)) as saldoestoque
from produto p
inner join itementrada e on p.idproduto = e.idproduto
inner join itemsaida s on p.idproduto = s.idproduto
where e.da between :data_inicial and :data_final
group by p.idproduto, p.descricaoproduto
order by p.descricaoproduto
```

Ex: Foram duas entradas, uma de 100un e outra de 230un e duas saidas de 1un cada.

Deveria mostrar entrada=330 e saida=2, mas mostra entrada=990un e saida=6un

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/466202/join-avan%C3%A7ado-em-firebird-n%C3%A3o-consigo-juntar-as-tabelas-que-preciso-e-ordenar?noredirect=1

Comment: Obrigado Motta. Ajudou e consegui resolver o problema.